# How to Make addEventListener work on submit

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

am having problem making this to work on submit
it works well when using

```
document.getElementById("gets").addEventListener("click", b_button);
```

but not workng when i use

```
document.getElementById("gets").addEventListener("submit", b_button);
```

is there away to make it work on submit than using click

```
    <form method="post">
          
              <button type="submit" id="gets">Submit</button>
             <p id="error"></p>
            
   
          </form>
    
   
    <script>
       function b_button() {
    document.getElementById("gets").disabled = true;
    var time_meter = 10;
    var runTimer = setInterval(function() {
        if (time_meter <= 0) {
            clearInterval(runTimer);
            document.getElementById("error").innerHTML = "";
        } else {
            document.getElementById("error").innerHTML = 'counting ' + time_meter;
        }
        time_meter -= 1;
    }, 1000);
    setTimeout(function() {
        document.getElementById("gets").disabled = false;
    }, 10000);

}

document.getElementById("gets").addEventListener("submit", b_button);
    </script>
```

Comment: If you are going to submit, you will leave the current page, so why bother updating the current page on submit? If you want to stay on the page, don't use a submit button, just use a regular button.

Comment: hmm no problem i can give it a try if you provide a sample code

Comment: The `submit`-event fires when the user submits a `form`. `button` is the child element of the `form` so it can't receive bubbled events of the parent `form`-element.

Comment: Target `gets` and then call it's parent so you can bind the event listener to the Form.

Comment: See also: `Note that the submit event fires on the <form> element itself, and not on any <button> or <input type="submit"> inside it.` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/submit_event

Answer (score 1):

you have to listen to form submit not to button submit

```
<form id="form" method="post">

document.getElementById("form").addEventListener("submit", function(e){ .... }
```

do not forget on `e.preventDefault();` inside of your code to prevent unwanted submiting

Comment: If you don't want the form to submit, you shouldn't be setting up a submit handler only to cancel the submit. The solution here is to use a regular button and its `click` event.